# UML Class Diagram - A user can't send a message to another user if he's not interessted in his offer

Tags: uml, class-diagram

As the title mention, i have 3 classes : User, Offer, Message.
There is a constraint : A user can't send a message to another user if he's not interessted in his offer.
How do i model this case?! where i should add the proper attributes?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a constraint which belongs to a use case.

There are too many different ways this constraint can be implemented. So you can not infer that constraint to any class construct directly.

Comment: Hi @Thomas Kilian, 
Can you suggest one?!

Comment: You mean a way to implement it? No. That's by far off-topic. You can simply ignore messages, route them via buffers or block the sender. You need to decide that on an architects suggestion knowing the domain.

Comment: that was helful, Thanks!